How to find nuclear color transparency in following reaction?
I am doing my project on Nuclear Color transparency which involves calculating color transparency for nuclear reaction $h+A\rightarrow h+N+(A-1)$.
In a nuclear reaction, the nuclear Color transparency is given by the following integral $$T=\frac{1}{A}\int d^3r\rho(\textbf{r})\mathscr{P}_0(\textbf{p}_0,r)\mathscr{P}_1(\textbf{p}_1,r)\mathscr{P}_2(\textbf{p}_2,r),$$
where $A$ is mass number of the nuclease, $\textbf{p}_0$ is momentum of incoming hadron, $\textbf{p}_1$ is momentum of outgoing hadron, and $\textbf{p}_2$ is momentum of knocked-out nucleon. Furthermore, $\mathscr{P}_i(\textbf{p}_i,r)$ is the probability that no interaction occurs to the $i^{th}$ hadron (survival probability of $i^{th}$ hadron), and is given by the expression $$\mathscr{P}_i(\textbf{p}_i,r)=\exp \Big(-\int_{path}dz\sigma(\textbf{p}_i,z)\rho(z) \Big),$$
where integration is taken along the physical path of the hadron between the interaction point and the nuclear surface, and $\sigma(\textbf{p}_i,z)$ is the effective cross-section, and $z$ is the distance from the point of hard interaction. $\rho$ is Woods-Saxon nuclear density $\rho(r)=\frac{c}{1+\exp\left(\frac{R-r}{0.56}\right)}$, $c$ and $R$ being constant.
Finally, I am taking the quantum-diffusion model derived from the perturbative-QCD model in which $\sigma$ is given as follows $$\sigma=M\left[\left\{\frac{z}{l}+N\left[1-\frac{z}{l}\right]\right\}\theta(l-z)+\theta(z-l)\right],$$ where $M$ and $N$ are model specific constants, $l$ is hadron coherent length, and $\theta$ is Heaviside step function.
This is the initial stage of my project work and I am reading this paper. I understood the basic model but I was unable to calculate the integral in the survival probability. I have been stuck in this step for the last week and tried many methods, I even consulted with my friends in the mathematics department but they are also equally lost. The paper does not go into detail about their methods. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you.
If you need any other details about the problem I am facing kindly ask.
